# If $k \in \mathbb {N}$ and $n \in \mathbb {N}$ ; Prove that $\frac {2^{2 (3 k + n)} + 24 (4^k + 6)}{2 (4^{k + 3 n} - 216)}\notin \mathbb {N}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that, if $k \in \mathbb {N}$ and $n \in \mathbb {N}$ ;
$$\frac {2^{2 (3 k + n)} + 24 (4^k + 6)}{2 (4^{k + 3 n} - 216)}\notin\mathbb {N}$$

At the moment, I'm afraid I do not know any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that this number is not a natural number? In this case you can maybe try a double induction: start with $k = 1$ and use induction on $n$ (this will be the base case for $k$), and then use induction on $k$.

Comment: @Klaramun yes i do not know the mathematical symbols well.You got it right the question.

Comment: Can $k$ and/or $n$ be $0$?

Comment: @ajotatxe $n,k$ must be only positive integer numbers

Comment: Yes, but it does not seem easy at all. The denominator can be lesser or greater than numerator (depending on $k$ and $n$), and there is no common factor to the denominators.

Comment: @ajotatxe Could it be an Olympiad question?

Comment: I don't know. Where did you find it?

Comment: @ajotatxe The teacher gave me a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not an answer**. Only some facts that might (or might not) help.

$$2^{2(3k+n)}+24(4^k+6)=2^{6k+2n}+3\cdot 2^{2k+3}+2^4\cdot 3^2=2^4(2^{6k+2n-4}+3\cdot2^{2k-1}+3^2)$$

$$2(4^{k+3n}-216)=2^{2k+6n+1}-2^4\cdot3^3=2^4(2^{2k+6n-3}-3^3)$$

Then we must see if $D_{k,n}=2^{2k+6n-3}-3^3$ can divide $N_{k,n}=2^{6k+2n-4}+3\cdot2^{2k-1}+3^2$.

It is not difficult to see that $D_{k,n}\le N_{k,n}$ implies $k\ge n$.

I have computed $v_{k,n}=\gcd(N_{k,n},D_{k,n})$ for $1\le n\le k\le 100$. These are $5050$ cases. I have obtained $1$ in most cases, prime numbers in $152$ and composite numbers in $4$ cases. Among these $156$ in which $v_{k,n}\neq 1$, there are $121$ that are $19$ or a multiple of $19$.

Comment: Hmm..It's İnteresting..